# I need to split the number into blocks. Rsa encryption task

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wrote a code that turns text into ASCII. but now according to the algorithm, I need to split the number into blocks m[1],m[2],m[3]...m[n] : m[i] <N. N = p * q. Here is my code below.
But when I try to split a number on a block using "while", it gives the error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" although I checked the type "str_values" and it shows "int".

It should turn out something like this: If N = 2106053, then we take a list of blocks (numbers) ['104101', '1081081', '1132119', '111114', '108100'] the same condition must be met that m[i] should not start with 0, so we have m[1] not '1041011' because then m[2] = [081081] and this is not a number. I hope you understand me :)

I don't fully understand python syntax, tell me what is my mistake and how can I write this algorithm.
`

```
p = 1039
   q = 2027
   if isprime(p) and isprime(q):
       N = p * q
       fiN = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
   else:
       print('not prime')
   print(N, fiN)
   e = 17
   d = pow(e, -1, fiN)
   d1 = [N, e]
   print('open - ', d1)
   d2 = [N, d]
   print('secret - ', d2)
   text = input("enter a string to convert into ascii values: ")
   ascii_values = [ord(character) for character in text]
   print(ascii_values)
   str_values = int(''.join(map(str, ascii_values)))
   a = list(str(str_values))
   print(type(str_values))
   print(a)
   k = 0
   i=0
   while k < N:
       k = a[i] + a[i + 1]

   print(k)
```

```
-Example
2106053 2102988
open -  [2106053, 17]
secret -  [2106053, 1360757]
enter a string to convert into ascii values: hello world
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
<class 'int'>
['1', '0', '4', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '8', '1', '0', '8', '1', '1', '1', '3', '2', '1', '1', '9', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '4', '1', '0', '8', '1', '0', '0']
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this snippet, you expect somehow the a's to be integers, aren't you?

```
while k < m:
   k = a[i] + a[i + 1]
```

They are not. `k` and `m` are initialized with integer values but after the first loop, `k` contains a `str` value because the list `a` contains instances of `str` hence the `TypeError` exception.
If you must keep that list of strings, the best you can do is:

```
while k < m:
   k = int(a[i]) + int(a[i + 1])
```